# VBScript: Trim characters from left of folder names

Tags: vbscript, rename, directory

I would like to trim an **x** amount of characters from the left of multiple folders.

*Imagine having these folder names:*

```
01.a-foldername
02.b-foldername
03.c-foldername
```

*After being processed by the VBscript they become:*

```
a-foldername
b-foldername
c-foldername
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove `N` characters from the beginning of a string or how to rename folders?

Answer (score 1):

Use Mid:

[Mid(string,start[,length])](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_mid.asp)

So in your example above

```
Mid(4)
```

Of interest: [VBScript Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp)